# When I reserve memory with VirtualAlloc() and MEM_RESERVE, shouldn't I be able to grow my allocation on a 64K boundary?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, allocation, virtual-memory

First of all, I very well know how `VirtualAlloc()` works: when I reserve blocks of memory, I get addresses aligned to 64K boundaries, (a value which can be easily obtained by `GetSystemInfo()`), then when I commit pages, I get them on a page size boundary, usually 4K.

The thing I can't get, is why if I call `VirtualAlloc()` with the `MEM_RESERVE` flag (so I'm reserving pages) and I specify a certain size, let's say 4096, then I won't be able to grow further this region up to 64K?

What I'm saying is: when I commit pages I can use memory up to 4K because Windows alignes these commits to the page size (of course, I'm commiting pages!), but when I'm reserving regions of memory, shouldn't Windows align the size of the region I pass to `VirtualAlloc()` to 64K? Where all the "wasted" 15 pages go?

So if I reserve 4096 bytes, shouldn't I be able to commit more pages until 65536 bytes?
It doesn't seem so, because if I try this, `VirtualAlloc()` fails with the `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` last error code.

But why? If Windows really reserve pages on 64K boundaries, and I reserve pages on less than that size, will I loose the pages I don't reserve forever? Because it seems there is *no way* to commit them again, or to resize the region to fit the 64K boundaries I've missed with my lower reservation.

So, will the process' virtual space have holes?
To avoid this, do I have to reserve memory *always* on a 64K boundaries, so giving `VirtualAlloc()` a 64K-aligned value *always* when I'm reserving pages?

What about when I use `MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT`? Shoulnd't I pass 64K-aligned sizes also there, because of `MEM_RESERVE` flag?

I include a little code example I've tried.
As you can see here, the first functions succeeds, because I reserve more pages, then my commits will have enough "reserved region" to be actually committed, *but* also in this case, the region will be <64K, so where are those "lost" pages go?

In the second case, I've just `MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT`, so committing other pages just fails with the `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` last error code.
Fair enough, but also here, why can't I commit more pages, at least on the 64K boundary?
To not waste addresses and create these "holes", should I really reserve virtual memory on 64K boundaries? What about if I don't follow this principle? I always see *A LOT* of code around that simply calls `VirtualAlloc()` with `MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE` flags, *not* caring about this 64K align thing.
Are they allocating memory in the wrong way?
Thoughts?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define PAGE_SZ 4096


bool
reserve_and_commit()
{
  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mem_info;
    void * mem, * mem2;
bool result = true;

  mem =
    VirtualAlloc(0, PAGE_SZ * 1, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
  if (!mem)
  {
    result = false;
    printf("VirtualAlloc1: ERROR '%d'\n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
  }
  else
    printf("VirtualAlloc1: MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT OK. Address: %p\n", mem);

  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n\n");

  if (!VirtualQuery(mem, &mem_info, sizeof mem_info))
  {
    result = false;
    printf("VirtualQuery: ERROR '%d'\n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
  }
  else
    printf("VirtualQuery: OK. BaseAddress:%p AllocationBase:%p AllocationProtect:%08X "
           "RegionSize:%d State:%08X Protect:%08X Type:%08X\n",
           mem_info.BaseAddress, mem_info.AllocationBase, mem_info.AllocationProtect,
           (unsigned int)mem_info.RegionSize, (unsigned int)mem_info.State,
           (unsigned int)mem_info.Protect, (unsigned int)mem_info.State);

  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n\n");

  mem2 =
    VirtualAlloc(mem, PAGE_SZ * 2, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
  if (!mem2)
  {
    result = false;
    printf("VirtualAlloc2: ERROR '%d'\n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
  }
  else
    printf("VirtualAlloc2: MEM_COMMIT OK. Address: %p\n", mem2);

  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n\n");

  if (!VirtualFree(mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE))
  {
    result = false;
    printf("VirtualFree: ERROR '%d'\n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
  }
  else
    printf("VirtualFree: OK.\n");

  return result;
}


bool
first_reserve_and_then_commit()
{
  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mem_info;
  void * mem_reserved, * mem_committed;
  bool result = true;

  mem_reserved =
    VirtualAlloc(0, PAGE_SZ * 8, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
  if (!mem_reserved)
  {
    result = false;
    printf("VirtualAlloc1: ERROR '%d'\n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
  }
  else
    printf("VirtualAlloc1: MEM_RESERVE OK. Address: %p\n", mem_reserved);

  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n\n");

  if (!VirtualQuery(mem_reserved, &mem_info, sizeof mem_info))
  {
    result = false;
    printf("VirtualQuery1: ERROR '%d'\n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
  }
  else
   printf("VirtualQuery1: OK. BaseAddress:%p AllocationBase:%p AllocationProtect:%08X "
           "RegionSize:%d State:%08X Protect:%08X Type:%08X\n",
           mem_info.BaseAddress, mem_info.AllocationBase, mem_info.AllocationProtect,
           (unsigned int)mem_info.RegionSize, (unsigned int)mem_info.State,
           (unsigned int)mem_info.Protect, (unsigned int)mem_info.State);

  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n\n");

  mem_committed =
    VirtualAlloc(mem_reserved, PAGE_SZ * 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
  if (!mem_committed)
  {
    result = false;
    printf("VirtualAlloc2: ERROR '%d'\n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
  }
  else
    printf("VirtualAlloc2: MEM_COMMIT OK. Address: %p\n", mem_committed);

  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n\n");

  if (!VirtualQuery(mem_committed, &mem_info, sizeof mem_info))
  {
    result = false;
    printf("VirtualQuery2: ERROR '%d'\n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
  }
  else
    printf("VirtualQuery2: OK. BaseAddress:%p AllocationBase:%p AllocationProtect:%08X "
           "RegionSize:%ul State:%08X Protect:%08X Type:%08X\n",
           mem_info.BaseAddress, mem_info.AllocationBase, mem_info.AllocationProtect,
           (unsigned int)mem_info.RegionSize, (unsigned int)mem_info.State,
           (unsigned int)mem_info.Protect, (unsigned int)mem_info.State);

  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n\n");

  mem_committed =
    VirtualAlloc(mem_committed, PAGE_SZ * 8, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
  if (!mem_committed)
  {
    result = false;
    printf("VirtualAlloc3: ERROR '%d'\n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
  }
  else
    printf("VirtualAlloc3: MEM_COMMIT OK. Address: %p\n", mem_committed);

  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n\n");

  if (!VirtualFree(mem_reserved, 0, MEM_RELEASE))
  {
    result = false;
    printf("VirtualFree: ERROR '%d'\n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
  }
  else
    printf("VirtualFree: OK.\n");

  return result;
}



int main()
{
  first_reserve_and_then_commit();
  reserve_and_commit();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that in all your test cases you are *committing* memory you haven't previously *reserved*. From [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887.aspx): *"Attempting to commit a specific address range by specifying **MEM_COMMIT** without **MEM_RESERVE** and a non-**NULL*** lpAddress *fails unless the entire range has already been reserved. The resulting error code is **ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS**."*

Comment: VirtualAlloc() is a very low-level way to manage address space, granularity is a very basic way to limit fragmentation and keep the processor paging tables from exploding.  When you start fretting about the kind of things you are talking about then you should be using HeapAlloc() instead.

Comment: @IInspectable as you can see from the code, I *NEVER* commit memory without before reserving it. Only in the second example the memory I try to commit is greater than the memory reserved, *but* only to test if I could commit some memory considering the reserved memory has 64K boundaries or not, but it seems Windows forces me to commit only according to the reserve size I've specified, thus ignoring the 64K boundary. That's exactly what I wanted to prove, then I ask: What happens to the non-reserved pages outside the 64K boundaries? Will the system reuse them someway?

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your advice, but for this specific thing I need `VirtualAlloc()`. As far as I'm understanding, one should *always* reserve memory asking the system sizes aligned to 64K, even when using the `MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT` flags combined, right?

Comment: The system cannot *reuse* unused **address space**, due to the granularity imposed. The reasons for this have been [outlined by Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586303/when-i-reserve-memory-with-virtualalloc-and-mem-reserve-shouldnt-i-be-able-t?noredirect=1#comment51125742_31586303). No memory is lost. Not depleting reserved memory merely pokes holes into the available address space. It is unclear, why you seem to be unable to follow the documented contract. If you cannot waste address space, you need to reserve address space in multiples of 64k.

Comment: You also appear to be very confused about the rules. While you claim to *"NEVER commit memory without before reserving it"*, you then go on to say that *"only [...] the memory I try to commit is greater than the memory reserved."* You are contradicting yourself. You may wish to reread the MSDN pages on [Memory Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366779.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As demonstrated by your program, virtual pages aren't automatically reserved when allocated. When you reserve a single page with `VirtualAlloc` an entire 64K block of pages is allocated, but only a single page is reserved. You can only commit pages that have been reserved, so when your program tries to commit the allocated but unreserved pages the call to `VirtualAlloc` fails.

As for why it works this way, the simple answer is that this is the way it's documented to work. Nowhere in the documentation does it state that `VirtualAlloc` will ever reserve more pages than you ask it to. I don't have any insight on why exactly Microsoft chose to implement this way, but it seems it meets the principle of least astonishment. In particular, by keeping it mostly a hidden implementation detail, it means that less programs would break if they were to decide to change the allocation granularity size (However, at this point I don't think it's possible for Microsoft to change this.) It also might reduce the memory needed for keeping track of reserved pages.

As for what's the best practice when using `VirtualAlloc` my recommendation is that it should normally only be used to allocate memory in sizes greater than 64K and ideally much bigger. But since no physical memory is lost when allocating regions smaller than 64K, just virtual address space, for many programs it doesn't matter. As a debugging aid, I once used a custom version of malloc in a program so that it used `VirtualAlloc` for all allocations, most of which were much smaller than 4K, let alone 64K.

Comment: Thanks for your insight on this matter. I guess Microsoft just chosen this 64K for how the systems keeps the virtual address space consistent with its data structure such as VAD Trees. Said that, you say that no physical memory is lost when allocating regions smaller than 64K and this is true, but it is also true that if you do that, you may create kind of "holes" and fragmentation in your *virtual* address space, since you're creating some pages' reserved addresses that can't be neither reserved nor committed in any way. Am I wrong in assuming this, and so aligning vmem reserves to 64K?

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci Yes, when you allocate less than 64K you end up with a range of wasted pages that can't be reserved or committed. So virtual address space goes to waste. But many programs don't come anywhere near exhausting their 2G virtual address space. Those that do have the easy solution these days of switching to 64-bit.

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking, but 32-bit applications have an address space of 4GB. Only 2GB (or 3GB) is available for application use on a 32-bit system. On a 64-bit system, a 32-bit application can use the entire 4GB address space (as long as it claims to be *large address aware*).

Comment: @RossRidge thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to hear. Of course many programs don't come anywhere near to exhausting their 2GB, 3GB or whatever, but this is not a reason to create fragmentation and "holes", a good program should be a perfect automation which considers everything, and how its underlying system works, among other things. Thanks again for your insight.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for pointing it out, but I guess we all know how that works, we were just speaking generally, considering another kind of problem, forgetting for a second those details. But, again, thanks for adding some more information for the readers.

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci: If you are looking for a runtime environment, that doesn't suffer from memory fragmentation (one way or another), you'd have to go with .NET. While not perfect, its compacting heap beats any native CRT heap implementation. Little known fact: The heap as implemented in the CRT that ships with Visual Studio will not ever shrink.

Comment: @IInspectable, well, it depends. On versions prior to the .Net runtime 4.5, objects that were larger than 85,000 bytes were allocated on a non-compacting heap (the large-object heap) that was susceptible to fragmentation. On version 4.5 they introduced some changes that reduce the fragmentation risk and they also added a mechanism to manually request a one-shot large-object-heap compaction the next time the Garbage Collector runs. Cheers!

Comment: @BlueStrat: The point I was trying to make is, that since .NET allows for objects to move in memory during their lifetime, a compacting heap is possible. The C++ programming environment doesn't allow for this, as objects need to stay at the same address throughout their lifetime.

Comment: @IInspectable, yes I see and agree fully with your point. Mine was just to be cautious because (by experience) if the size of the objects you are regularly handling under .Net is relatively large, they will become unmovable and thus, susceptible to fragmentation. At least on the latest versions you can manually request a compaction. On earlier versions you were out of luck! Cheers =)

Comment: This [blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031008-00/?p=42223) on msdn explains it, without actually explaining why they did it. This he posts in the comments below.